# Function to check if a string is backslashed for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, escaping

Since there is no function to check whether a string is escaped before entering it to the db, how can I do this with regex?

```
$string = 'some" string';
if(!preg_match('//',$string))
{
   $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($string);
}
```

php manual:

> mysqli_real_escape_string backslashes characters encoded NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Comment: It's not hard to check if there are backslashes before certain characters, but it's impossible to check if the backslashes in a chunk of text are appropriate for any arbitrary application.

Comment: This previous answer has it right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065391/php-what-happens-when-a-string-is-double-times-mysqlirealescapestring/2065428#2065428

Comment: Please, please, please, just structure your code so that the only place you call mysqli_real_escape_string is just before you create your sql statement. Then you don't need to know if it has already been done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to do this.

If you try to come up with a way to know for sure whether a string is escaped or not, someone can just come in and make a string that will fool your detection method.

For example, if you used "\" as a test to make sure slashes are escaped, I can just give you a string like `"'; DROP DATABASE dbname(); --\\"`, which passes your inspection but is still horribly wrong.

If you can't use stored procedures and/or proper parameter handling for whatever reason, the only way to make sure your strings are clean is to clean every string for every untrusted source.

Answer (score 4):

There is no function to check whether a string is escaped, because there is no logical way to tell if a string is escaped.

```
It\'s nice
```

Is that escaped? How do you know? Is it an escaped apostrophe, or an unescaped backslash and apostrophe?

Escaping is a process, not a property of a string. You must always know whether you've escaped a string for a particular context. The best way to do that is to keep your strings raw and unescaped until the time they leave for another context. So don't call `mysql_real_escape_string` until you're actually concatenating into an SQL string. Don't call `htmlspecialchars` until the moment you're echoing into HTML output.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.
Use prepared statements and bound variables. Refer to [mysqli_prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).